# Creating a Nodejs server that send response with multipart form data

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

There are lots of posts about how to handle request with multipart form data . But my use case is that I have a client that expects multipart form data response from server, and I need to write a simple nodejs server in order to test my client.

To write the simple server, I have the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var FormData = require('form-data');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/describe', function(req, res) {
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('part1', 'part 1 data');
  form.append('part2', 'part 2 data');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  res.send(form);
});

app.listen(3030, "0.0.0.0");
console.log('Listening on port 3030...');
```

Now when my client request localhost:3030/describe, the response header shows the following without the boundary value

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
```

And the content is downloaded as file instead of in the response body.

```
{"_overheadLength":208,"_valueLength":22,"_valuesToMeasure":[],"writable":false,"readable":true,"dataSize":0,"maxDataSize":2097152,"pauseStreams":true,"_released":false,"_streams":["----------------------------315683163006570790405079\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"part1\"\r\n\r\n","part 1 data",null,"----------------------------315683163006570790405079\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"part2\"\r\n\r\n","part 2 data",null],"_currentStream":null,"_boundary":"--------------------------315683163006570790405079"}
```

So my questions:
1. how do we make the boundary appears in the response header?
2. how do we make the form data response content show up in the response body instead as download file?

Comment: One fundamental issue here is that the HTTP protocol never intended `multipart/form-data` as part of a response cycle, but only as part of the request cycle. If you want the browser to understand the various fields in the body, you'll need to implement your own client-side parser for the response from the server, as this is a very unconventional API.

Comment: thank you Patrick! Yes I have to write my own client-side parser to understand the response from the server and would like to make sure my client side parsing logic can work with any real life form-data response, not just the one sent from my test server. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To send your form data you'll want to pipe it (see [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data#alternative-submission-methods)), like this:

```
form.pipe(res);
```

To add the boundary into the header, you can do something like this:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+form.getBoundary());
```

Now, about the "save as" box: The browser uses content-type to figure out what to do with the file. So if you want it to be displayed in the browser window, a good choice would be `text/plain` (or possibly `text/html` if that doesn't work). Then you could put your `multipart/form-data` into something like `x-content-type`.

(I'm assuming eventually you'll be using XHR or fetch, and at that point you can switch the `content-type` back. the `text/plain` thing is just a temporary solution to get the data to show up in a standard web browser for testing.)

Putting it all together:

```
app.get('/describe', function(req, res) {
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('part1', 'part 1 data');
  form.append('part2', 'part 2 data');
  res.setHeader('x-Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+form._boundary);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  form.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Thank you David784! Your suggestion definitely worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jing you're welcome...if you get a chance, would you mind upvoting and accepting the answer?

Comment: the 'content-type', not 'Content-Type', because body.js is obtaining content type by: const ct = this.headers.get('content-type'); if (ct.startsWith('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')). It becomes null otherwise and error is thrown.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, it was POST request that was being called by a webhook and I used `multer` did the magic too. Here is the code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', upload.none(), function (req, res) {
  console.log("Data",req.body) 
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Your solution is about sending request with multipart/form-data, not response.

Comment: @cedenzah My solution works for me. Like I said I was trying to get data from a webhook. `req.body` sends has the data I need from the webhook.