# How to send image files alongside with JSON data through HTTP requests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http

I'm building an app, with React.js and Express.js, in which the user can create a quiz, and I want it to be able to use text and images to illustrate each question and each option. By now, the structure of the data beeing sent through front-end and back-end is something like this:

```
{
"title": "Quiz title",
"description": "This is my example of description",
"questions": [
    {
        "optionsText": ["A", "B","C"],
        "questionText": "chose one letter, please",
        "selectedRightOptionNumber": 0
    },
    {
        "optionsText": ["D", "E","F"],
        "questionText": "chose one letter, please",
        "selectedRightOptionNumber": 2
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I send the images alongside the data? Remember that I need to know in the back-end which image belongs to which question, option or if it is the main quiz image.

Comment: You can convert the files to base64 and then add it as a property on the json object you send to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Q: How to send image files alongside with JSON data through HTTP requests?

A: At the HTTP/Response level, that's easy.

I'd recommend sending the response as a [MIME/MultiPart](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) payload.  Just as you would send an e-mail with attachments, for example.

Note: MIME/MultiPart image attachments are base64 encoded.  EVeras suggests simply base64-encoding the images directly in your JSON (as opposed to wrapping both the JSON and the images).  This approach would probably work, too :)

In any case, please look at this thread:

[Creating a Nodejs server that send response with multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50883981/421195)

Comment: Using the suggestion from EVeras I can just attach the images in the JSON inside the question they belong, but if I use the MIME/MultiPart, is there a way to easily know where the image belongs?